# iPhone like uiimagepicker controller in iPad view

Tags: ipad, video, uiimagepickercontroller

Basically I want to have a window/UIView in my iPad App that allows you to record while doing other things at the same time.

Hence I decided to create a UIView, created a UIViewController Class/NIB Files for iPhone, and attempted to call the uiimagepicker in there, hoping the iPhone version will be called.

However, the iPad version gets called and the whole screen is filled with the video picker.

Is there any way I can multi-task video recording and display something else in my screen?

Comment: I don't think that it's possible

Comment: but i can do it via a popover right? yeah..i don't want to use a popover